# How to debug Angular client application through proxy in VS Code with Chrome Debugger

Tags: angular, debugging, proxy, visual-studio-code

I setup a proxy for my Angular client application in order to route the request to server mock app.
I run my application using command **npn run proxy** :

- "proxy": "ng serve  --open  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json "

What Chrome **debugger configurations** do i need to make in order to start my app in **debug mode** but still to run the requests through the **proxy**?

running env:

- Angular CLI: 6.0.0
- Node: 8.11.1
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I order to debug an Angular 2+ app using Google Chorme, you have to run it in dev mode. You can make sure if your app is running in development by checking this line in Developer Console: "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.". You will have source maps for your .ts files and you will be able to add break points. Just search using Ctrl + P for your files.